# Diagnosing 2011 Macbook Air Webcam

Tags: macos, webcam

## SYMPTOMS

1. FaceTime indicates no camera is available
2. The website: [WebCam Test](https://webcamtests.com/) indicates a webcam could not be found
3. OS X Version 10.11.6 "System Report" Hardware -> Camera -> No video capture devices were found

The camera was last used with FaceTime in January.

## QUESTION

Are there any command line diagnostics that can be performed to determine why the Webcam is unavailable?

## UPDATE

Apple Hardware Test Results: No camera list under "Hardware Profile" Tab.

```
Alert! Apple Hardware test has detected an error.
4HDD/11/4000000:SATA(0,0)
```

Comment: did you reset your SMC ? and PRAM ?

Answer (score 1):

Chances are your OS X installation is broken.

First run Apple Hardware Test, restart and hold `D`.

Still not showing in System Hardware profile ? Slim chance but it wont hurt, reset your SMC and PRAM.

Still not working ...

Make backup to Time machine (external drive)

Restore your OSX , restart and hold `Command-R` that will get you in to Restore screen. Follow the instructions.

Still not working...add new MacBook Air to your Christmas wish list.

Buy a cheep USB video camera so you can survive till then.